# View doesn't get updated when item is added to array

Tags: knockout.js

**Backstory**

I'm trying to create a page where I can edit a created portfolio using .NET MVC and Knockout.js. My *portfolio* contains 1 or more *portfolio items* which in turn can have 0 or more *images*.

So I could have a *portfolio* called "Webdesign", which contain *portfolio items* representing the different clients i've designed a website for every client can have multiple *images* containing shots of the design.

Using AJAX from my view I call the .NET MVC controller, which returns my *portfolio*, *portfolio items* and *images* as JSON.

**Problem**

The view basicly works fine initially, the observables contain the correct data and everything is being displayed as It should. The problem occurs when I want to add *images* to a *portfolio item*. When I click the add image ("Voeg een afbeelding toe") button the addImage function is called and the image is pushed into the correct array but the view doesn't get updated.

**Code**

Below you'll find the code broken down to the bare essentials, also see the link to a working example at the bottom. What It should do is display the ID of the image which has already been added to the *portfolio item* and thus is present in the incoming JSON, which It does. When you click on the add image button ("Voeg afbeelding toe"), It should create an new *image* with the id set to 0, which It does, and update the view. So after you click on the add image button ("Voeg afbeelding toe") you should see 15 and 0 being displayed, but this doesn't happen.

**JSON**

```
{"PortfolioId":15,"Title":"test","Text":"\u003cp\u003etest\u003c/p\u003e\n","Image":null,"Published":false,"Created":"maandag 10 februari 2014 14:13","PortfolioItems":[{"PortfolioId":15,"Id":15,"Title":"Titel","Text":"Text","Images":[{"Id":1,"ImageLink":"http://google.nl","ImageLinkTarget":null,"ImageUrl":null}],"Placeholder":null,"Published":false,"SortOrder":19,"Created":"maandag 10 februari 2014 14:13"}]};
```

**Javascript**

```
function PortfolioEditViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var json ={"PortfolioId":15,"Title":"test","Text":"\u003cp\u003etest\u003c/p\u003e\n","Image":null,"Published":false,"Created":"maandag 10 februari 2014 14:13","PortfolioItems":[{"PortfolioId":15,"Id":15,"Title":"Titel","Text":"Text","Images":[{"Id":1,"ImageLink":"http://google.nl","ImageLinkTarget":null,"ImageUrl":null}],"Placeholder":null,"Published":false,"SortOrder":19,"Created":"maandag 10 februari 2014 14:13"}]};

    //## PROPERTIES ##
    {
        self.PortfolioId = ko.observable('');
        self.Title = ko.observable('');
        self.Text = ko.observable('');
        self.Image = ko.observable('');
        self.Published = ko.observable('');
        self.Created = ko.observable('');
        self.PortfolioItems = ko.observableArray();        
    }   
    //## SERVICES ##
    {
        //Normally I get this data using Ajax

        self.PortfolioId = json.PortfolioId;
        self.Title = json.Title;
        self.Text = json.Text;
        self.Image = json.Image;
        self.Published = json.Published;
        self.Created = json.Created;
        self.PortfolioItems(json.PortfolioItems);  
    }

    //## FUNCTIONS ##
    self.addPortfolioItem = function () {        
        self.PortfolioItems.push({
            Title: "",
            Text: "",
            Images: ko.observableArray(),
            Placeholder: "",
            Published: false,
            SortOrder: $("#sortable tbody tr").length + 1
        });
    };

    self.addImage = function (item) {
        //Pushes item into array but view doesn't get updated
        item.Images.push({
            Id: 0,
            ImageUrl: "",
            ImageLink: "",
            ImageLinkTarget: ""
        });          
    };

}
var portfolioEditViewModel = null;
function initPortfolioEdit() {
    portfolioEditViewModel = new PortfolioEditViewModel();    
    ko.applyBindings(portfolioEditViewModel, document.getElementById("portfolioEditContainer"));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    initPortfolioEdit();    
});
```

**View**

```
<div id="portfolioEditContainer">    
    <section class="contentMain">
        <div class="container">        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <table class="width_100 table table-hover" id="sortable">
                                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: PortfolioItems}">
                                        <tr>                                                                               
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="#" class="pzzl-btn" data-bind='click: $root.addImage'>
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> <strong>Voeg afbeelding toe</strong>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr> 
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2">
                                                <table class="width_100">
                                                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: Images}">                                                        
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                                                    </tr> 
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>                                                            
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>     
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>                                                        
                        </tr>   
                    </table>
                </div>                                                  
            </div>            
        </div>    
    </section>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffbDs/1/)

Comment: Shouldn't the services section be self.Title(json.Title).  I don't think you can use the = operator to assign in knockout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PortfolioItems` that you are adding in the initialization (`self.PortfolioItems(json.PortfolioItems)`) have not been mapped to define `Images` as an observableArray.

So, for the initial data, `Images` is a plain array and is not able to notify on changes like an observableArray.

You would want to loop through the items and ensure that `Images` is an observableArray.

Here is one possible solution where the array is mapped : http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ffbDs/3/

Comment: Thought that might be the problem, will try and update the question :) Edit: Worked! Thanks :)